# Is Tridion (Sites and Docs) vulnerable to log4shell?

Tags: tridion-docs, tridion-sites

I am surprised nobody asked this yet, so putting it here for some easy points.

I'll choose the most complete answer as the correct one next week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Tridion Sites** - core product unaffected but customers may still be affected in a custom web application.

**Tridion Docs**  - core product unaffected but on-site customers should check any DITA-OT/customizations using log4j.

This library is used in some of the other RWS products here you can find the full detailed list of products affected and not affected by [Critical Apache Log4J2 CVE-2021-44228 Vulnerability (Log4Shell).](https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000017712) and the Mitigation Guidance which was created by RWS Support.

Comment: We used the above link too. It is pretty exhaustive and provides pointers to almost all of the RWS products